# Проверка наличия ключа в dict из list

Tags: python-3.x

Подскажите, мне нужно из list проверить, есть ли такой ключ в словаре

у меня есть функция, где я в list добавляю нужные мне значения

```
ngram.append(text[i:i + n])
```

затем мне нужно добавить эти значения из списка в словарь как ключ и присвоим им значение 0.0, если ключ уже есть, то просто продолжить дальше

```
for key in ngram:
    if key in current_dict:
        continue
    current_dict[key] = 0.0
```

но получаю ошибку

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

пример:
`ngram=['ab','bc','sd','ab']`,
а нужно получить `current_dict={'ab':0.0; 'bc':0.0; 'sd':0.0}`

п.с. больше всего мне не понятно, что это работает, хотя `text` тоже `list`

```
for key in text:
    if key in current_dict:
        current_dict[key] += 1
```

Comment: А вы напечатайте `print(ngram)` перед циклом `for key in ngram:`, я почти уверен, что у вас там не совсем то, что вы думаете. Где-то там притаился список внутри списка. И покажите более полный трейс ошибки. Там должна быть указана конкретная строка кода, в которой выходит ошибка. Это важно.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо большое, действительно оказалось, что у меня список списков. теперь все работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в словаре есть замечательный метод `get()`, в котором можно указывать значение по умолчанию и тогда можно сделать такой трюк:

```
for key in ngram:
    current_dict[key] = current_dict.get(key, 0.0)
```

вообще если вам надо инициализировать словарь, то ничего не мешает сделать прямо в лоб:

```
current_dict = dict((key, 0.0) for key in ngram)
```

вы получите то, что требуется

касательно приведенного кода:

```
for key in text:
    if key in current_dict:
        current_dict[key] += 1
```

то скорее всего имеется в виду подсчет кол-ва встречающихся значений в списке и тогда корректно это делать так:

```
current_dict = dict()
for key in ngram:
    current_dict[key] = current_dict.get(key, 0) + 1
```

т.е. такой код подсчитает кол-во вхождений значений в список и сформирует словарь

Comment: `dict((key, 0.0) for key in ngram)` - может лучше использовать сразу *словарное сокращение* `{key: 0.0 for key in ngram}`, а не подавать на вход словаря генератор? )  Как-то это выглядит избыточным.

Comment: Или даже так: `dict.fromkeys(ngram, 0.0)`

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать метод `dict.setdefault` [ссылка](https://pythonz.net/references/named/dict.setdefault/).

```py
for key in ngram:
    current_dict.setdefault(key, 0.0)
```

Также для решения Вашей проблемы Вы можете использовать `collections.defaultdict` [ссылка](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```py
from collections import defaultdict

current_dict = defaultdict(float)

for key in text:
    current_dict[key] += 1
```